# Avoid data polling for Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

So basically, right now i'm currently call API from the backend every 2 second to get the realtime if there's any changes occur. What i'm facing is polling which is not good since it can drain handphone battery. Is there a way for me to avoid polling, for example the app can detect only if there's changes with the database

Comment: How about using Firebase and pushing messages to the app whenever there is a database change (from your backend)?

Comment: @JulienLachal you have any reference? is it using the push notification cloud messaging?

Comment: give [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup) a look, they even have examples.